# Should you ALWAYS use Blender's subsurface modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I'm creating a spaceship right now and was wondering if it's always necessary to use a subsurface modifier?

I've used the modifier in my mesh so far, but it would be much easier to not use it. I hate constantly adding loop cuts in order to get edges

Comment: you should show us how your spaceship looks like.

Comment: There are a lot of close votes on this question as if it was primarily opinion based, but I do not believe it is. The question is not if it is **better** to use Subsurf, but if it is **necessary**. There can be a definite not opinion based right answer - No, it is not necessary since other modelling workflows are available.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Whether you should depends mainly on the intended use of the model and its geometry.

A model that only appears in the background may not need the benefit of the modifier and render time will be reduced if it is not present.

Not all models require the benefit. If all of the surfaces of a model are flat, like the boards in a picket fence, then the subsurf is not necessary and the rounding that gives realism to edges can be provided by a bevel modifier.

Not all that do require edge loops. Often a judicious application of the bevel modifier will produce good results, with the advantage that the bevel modifier is non destructive. This can provide advantages when creating or changing models.

Answer (score 0):

No, you really don't. You should only need it when you want to ensure that the end result will work the way you want it to and that your edge loops are flowing correctly, especially when you are working on complex geometry. Press Ctrl + 1 to turn it on, then ctrl + 0 to turn it off. If you are working on a ton of meshes, the easiest way I've found to turn them all off or on is to assign it to some value for a mesh, then copy that same modifier to all your meshes with ctrl + c.

But no, you don't always need to have it on. It will hurt you if you do that most of the time.